# How To Search An Object Property in An Array of Objects? Mongoose, MongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

**Edit:** I have solved my problem. The solution is in the comments.

I'm trying to allow users to link other accounts to their main accounts on my app. When they go to link an account I want to ensure the account they are trying to link has not already been linked by another User.

I can't seem to get the query right to search my database for any Users that have an account linked. I've successfully implemented functionality to create a new linked account, just need to finish ensuring it's not already taken.

My current query is as follows (where platformID and platform are passed correctly in the request and do already live in the database within the `linkedAccounts` array):

```
const profileExists = await User.findOne({linkedAccounts: {platformUserIdentifier: platformID, platform: platform}})
```

User scheme:

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    pic: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default:
        "https://icon-library.com/images/anonymous-avatar-icon/anonymous-avatar-icon-25.jpg",
    },
    linkedAccounts: [
      {
        platformUserIdentifier: String,
        platform: String
      }
    ],
  },
    {
      timestamps: true,
    }
);
```

My query feels correct to me but continues to return `null`. I've double-checked to ensure it doesn't relate to the variables from the request and I've also attached a screenshot of my database to prove what I'm searching for exists.

[MongoDB image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuKKl.png)

I'm at a roadblock and would really appreciate anyone's help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code I needed to use to find the account goes as follows:

```
const profileExists = await User.findOne({
     linkedAccounts: {$elemMatch: {platformUserIdentifier: platformID, platform: platform}}
  })
```

This returns the `User` profile that has the above `platformID` and `platform` in their `linkedAccounts`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with mongodb but in mongoose you have to find each key in object of array

```
const profileExists = await User.findOne({
  "linkedAccounts.platformUserIdentifier" : platformID,
  "linkedAccounts.platform" : platform
})
```

Playground for mongodb https://mongoplayground.net/p/NPGcUJl5MLw

Comment: Hi Pham,

Thanks for the reply. I tried implementing the code you shared above, however, I received a ```null``` value. I did some additional research and found the following code to work for me. I really appreciate your time and help.

const profileExists = await User.findOne({
      linkedAccounts: {$elemMatch: {platformUserIdentifier: platformUserIdentifier, 
      platform: platform}}
  })